# Still receiving sensor events after unregisterListener

Tags: java, android, events, sensors

I have noticed a lag between calling unregisterListener and when sensor events stop coming to my service. Is this normal? Is there a way to immediately stop receiving sensor events?

--
George

Comment: Which language/framework/library are you talking about?

Comment: I'm using Java (Eclipse 3.5 + ADK) and running on a Motorola Droid with OS 2.2.2. My app implements SensorEventListener and uses Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION. After I detect a particular event (device shaken or flipped) I want to cancel any subsequent sensor inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If the events fast then you may end up with more events than you want. Just set a `boolean` variable in your `Listener` and flip it as soon as you detected your first event. You can use that boolean then to determine if you want to continue with the code or not.